# Publish Gradle artefact that would be a copy of some existing artefact

Tags: gradle, dependabot

I have a set of Gradle modules with a shared version.
These modules are already used in other modules across organisation like this:

```
implementation("com.mycompany.somelib:somelib-x:$someLibVersion")
implementation("com.mycompany.somelib:somelib-y:$someLibVersion")
```

We did not have bom artefact previously.
We also have Dependabot that creates PRs every time the module version is changed.

Now I have to introduce backwards incompatible changes under one of the modules (let's call this module "xxx"). I am going to release this module under new artefactId ("xxx-v2").

However, I still want Dependabot to be able to update another modules. Therefore I need to publish new versions of the old artefact as a copy of some fixed (last) version of the old artefact.

I understand that this sounds crazy and probably the way to go is to manually update all usages of the old artefact.
But maybe there is trick in Dependabot / Gradle that could handle this in more elegant way?